# Is Azure Functions support Session storage?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was already know azure functions have two types of hosting ,

1. Server Less
2. On- premises

But  What i need to know is , Can i store My Login token to server less Azure functions ?

I have this doubt so i am not tried any thing i searched lot of things in google , But i am get clarification.

1. **I need server less azure functions API 's can support session maintenance or not?**
2. **Any alternative solutions is there to store my token ? Call other Authorized API's ?**

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sessions have meaning for web sites, not APIs. Are you trying to call an external service perhaps? Serverless functions are short-lived *stateless* APIs. Clients authenticate to them using tokens, which are then passed to downstream services.

Answer (score 1):

**Azure Functions are Stateless**

If you're wanting to store a session with data against it, you may want to take a look at something like [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cache/), you'll be able to get/set session data from Redis inside your functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So redis cache is one solution, Otherwise on premises  can support http funtions api or not?

Comment: @santhoshkumar I suspect you confuse APIs and web sites. *APIs* don't have sessions either (at least properly designed ones). Tokens are used to authenticate when calling APIs, including Functions. What are you trying to do?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Azure Functions don't have any session management as they're stateless (Including on-premises). 

You're going to have to use something else to manage that session whether it's Redis, CosmosDb or any other piece of software that fits your requirements.

Comment: @Charlie.H Durable functions do maintain state

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is not true. A session is from a logged in user and being able to know if they're authenticated / authorized to use an api or not. It's not just for websites. So the token you speak of would come from an authenticated user with a session. So if you're signed into a website you would get a cookie stored with token and if you weren't you would have to sign in to address the logged in user with a session.

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Functions** offers an alternative for creating **stateful functions** called Durable **Functions**. Durable **Functions** is an extension to the **Azure Functions** runtime that enables the definition of **stateful** workflows in code.

For more information follow the below docs.

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serverless-architecture/durable-azure-functions**

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview**

Comment: Thanks for your  answer, But Durable Functions is using for handling the timing of request, for an example if the request take 1 hour process means , we can use this. But what i need is , In my application i have 3 apis means, i api is login based on that token , i have to call other api's , What i am saying is [Authorise] for Other API's, I want get my token in other 2 apis

Comment: Durable functions are designed to maintain state; they not associated with long running operations. Not sure they useful for sessions though.

Comment: I don't think durable functions are analogous to sessions.  Sessions provide state across multiple HTTP requests tied to a sessionId typically tied to a user via a session or auth cookie.  Durable functions provide state within a workflow.  I.e. state across many small requests unique to a user, versus state for a long running workflow unique to that workflow.

Answer (score -2):

Yes Azure functions support session storage in this way. If you need to authenticate a user you will need some mechanism of doing that.

So for example if you're token exchange mechanism is AAD or B2C or a social like Facebook or Google or an open id connect authentication mechanism they would all be the mechanisms to authenticate/authorize a user and obtain a token and then store that as a user session.

An Azure function can certainly be apart of that process.

[App services and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#feature-architecture) use what is called "Easy Auth" or AuthZ middleware type functionality for handling incoming requests.

> The authentication and authorization middleware component is a feature of the platform that runs on the same VM as your application. When it's enabled, every incoming HTTP request passes through it before being handled by your application.

[image]

> The platform middleware handles several things for your app:

> - Authenticates users and clients with the specified identity provider(s)
> - Validates, stores, and refreshes OAuth tokens issued by the configured identity provider(s)
> - Manages the authenticated session
> - Injects identity information into HTTP request headers

> Calls from a trusted browser app in App Service to another REST API in App Service or Azure Functions can be authenticated using the server-directed flow. For more information, see Customize sign-ins and sign-outs.

So all in all, yes, there is a way to have a user session with azure functions. Now if you were comparing to express.js or fastify or asp.net you're not going to get the fine grained control as you may want on the call level. But it would be there on the IDP (identity provider level.)

So, if you were to define roles access and other things you could do that all through your IDP situation and then the token upon request would check your token to see if it were still valid and or see if you had to re-sign in.

As someone mentioned the primary driver of the session isn't from the api really but rather the client login. This would just be an extension of that client user journey. i.e. did you already do it if not you need to. SSO and other things regarding user session and auth come into those factors as well.